# Are there studies to find surface treatments to reduce the drag of an airfoil?

Tags: airfoil, drag, surface

I know that by designing an airplane or a car close to a teardrop, we can reduce the drag. My question has to do with the surface friction treatment. Some torpedoes glide in water more efficiently when wrapped in bubble cloaks.

Some feathers have textures to reduce friction. Some modern bathing suits textures help reduce friction.

Are there studies on surface treatments, such as texture, special paint, grooves, or perforations, to reduce drag?

## edit

Implied in my question is: If there are any results that do reduce skin friction, where have they been applied?

Comment: Literally [thousands](https://www.researchgate.net/search/publication?q=Aerodynamic%2Bdrag%2Breduction%2B)

Comment: @sophit  I think the question -- asked as "are there studies on this?" truly can be answered with what you have here and the slightest bit of elaboration.  Like a sentence or two on a couple of the studies and a link to each, followed by the link you posted supporting the statement "... and thousands more like these." The question is asking, has this been studied, and you provide conclusive proof that yes, in fact it sure has.

Comment: @RalphJ: Sorry I don't get your comment. Are you suggesting me to write a proper answer or not? 

Comment: Related: [What surface materials do airplanes use to reduce friction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/what-surface-materials-do-airplanes-use-to-reduce-friction)

Comment: A lot may depend on Reynolds number, but bubbles around the torpedo may be analogous to boundary layer studies.

Comment: @sophit Yes, please do

Comment: This seems to be _so_ broad that the only possible answer to the question is "Yes".

Comment: Do airplanes fly?

Comment: Here's one that I know of:  _"There’s a team of researchers at NASA’s Langley Research Center in Virginia who are studying ways to prevent the remains of insect impacts from sticking to the wing of an aircraft in flight .....  testing different coatings to see which do the best job at preventing bug build-up and the resulting disruption of air flow that reduces fuel efficiency._" From this document - [Nothing Bugs These NASA Aeronautical Researchers](https://www.nasa.gov/aeronautics/nothing-bugs-these-nasa-aeronautical-researchers)

Comment: Well, since nobody else is going to answer this... *Y'all are welcome.* ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are literally thousands of studies on the subject.  A keyword search on [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/search/publication?q=Aerodynamic%2Bdrag%2Breduction%2B) brings up many examples.  *(credit to Sophit)*

There's also a [similar question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/what-surface-materials-do-airplanes-use-to-reduce-friction) on this site that may be useful.  *(credit to Peter Kampf)*

And there are surface material [studies](https://www.nasa.gov/aeronautics/nothing-bugs-these-nasa-aeronautical-researchers/) for other purposes that you might also find interesting.  *(credit to Steve Pemberton)*